# Unknown column .... in 'where clause' when the Column Exists And Can't able to fix this - Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Feeling confused with this error..
Am using codeigniter and my code is this

```
public function get_all_rec_product(){
    $data = $this->db->select('*')
        ->from('tbl_product')
        ->order_by('pro_id','desc')
        ->where('rec_product','1')
        ->limit("3")
        ->get()
        ->result();
        return $data;
}
```

But I am getting this error everytime -

> Error Number: 1054
>
> Unknown column 'rec_product' in 'where clause'
>
> ```
> SELECT * FROM `tbl_product` WHERE `rec_product` = '1' ORDER BY
> `pro_id` DESC LIMIT 3
> ```

when another column is working perfectly which structure is same as rec_product..

```
public function get_all_top_product(){
    $data = $this->db->select('*')
        ->from('tbl_product')
        ->order_by('pro_id','desc')
        ->where('top_product','1')
        ->limit("4")
        ->get()
        ->result();
        return $data;
}
```

this query works perfectly for top_product column... But not wroking on rec_product column

```
MySql Query:

  ----------
  CREATE TABLE `tbl_product` (
  `pro_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `pro_title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `pro_desc` text NOT NULL,
  `pro_cat` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `pro_sub_cat` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `pro_brand` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `pro_price` float NOT NULL,
  `pro_quantity` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `pro_availability` tinyint(4) NOT NULL COMMENT 'status 1=instock, 2=outof stock, 3= up coming',
  `pro_status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1 COMMENT 'status=1 enable status=2 disable',
  `pro_image` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `top_product` tinyint(1) DEFAULT 0 COMMENT 'show top value=1 other wise value=0',
  `rec_product` tinyint(1) DEFAULT 0 COMMENT 'show top value=1 other wise value=0'
  ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

  ---------
```

Comment: Have you try to test your query directly in mysql panel? (phpmyadmin for ex.)

Comment: The answer to similar questions often is that the OP had multiple mysql instances / databases and they accidentally pointed the query to the wrong one, where the table had a different structure. Btw, when you execute `get_all_top_product()`, does the resultset include `rec_product` field?

Comment: yes, The query is already created in db.

Comment: No, executing get_all_top_product() gets the products from the tbl_product which matches the value of top_product column. And in the similar way I want to filter the recommended product by identifying the value where rec_product = 1

Comment: I got what the `get_all_top_product()` function does. However, it also issues a `select *` statement meaning it returns all columns from your table. So, does its output have the `rec_product` field you are looking for? If not, then that field does not exist, end of story.

Comment: Thanks Man, I have understood where I did the mistake! And fixed the problem

Answer (score 0):

you must bring down `->order_by` into `->where`
Because `where` clause is first condition compared by `order_by`

Example:

```
$get = this->db->select('*')->from('table')->where('id', $id)->get()->result();
```